# $rootScope not updating value

Tags: angularjs

I have an edit profile page with html code as follow:

```
<img ng-src="{$root.user.userProfilePic}" />
```

where `$rootScope.user.userProfilePic = "imageUrlHere" />`

However, when i updated the userProfilePic again using controller in the same page, the profile image is still remain the same. This does not occur if i use `$scope`. How could i fix it?

```
UpdateUserProfilePicApi.then(function (res) {
    $rootScope.user.userProfilePic = res.imgUrl;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing {{double braces}}, try this:

```
<img ng-src="{{user.userProfilePic}}" />
```

[ng-src docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using the **$root**.Try this :

```
<img ng-src="{{user.userProfilePic}}" />
```

This gives you expected result, because user.userProfilePic is evaluated and replaced by its value after angular is loaded.

```
<img ng-src="{$root.user.userProfilePic}" />
```

But with this, the browser tries to load an image named $root.user.userProfilePic, which results in a failed request. You can check this in the console of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use $root as $rootScope is accessible from all the views.
Remove $root from your code.

```
<img ng-src="{{user.userProfilePic}}" />
```